# LyX: Different margins for page numbers

Tags: margins, header-footer, page-numbering

How can I modify the page numbers to have a different SIDE margin.  I've got the vertical margin set right but my advisor wants my page numbers for the thesis 0.5" from both top and side edge (1" margin for the text). I'm using LyX.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}  % Delete current setting for header and footer

\fancypagestyle{main}{% page style for normal pages
  \fancyhfoffset[R]{0.5in}
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhfoffset[R]{0.25in}
  \fancyhead{}  % Get rid of headers and footers on plain pages...
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % ...and of the lines
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{
  \fancyhead{}  % Get rid of headers and footers on empty pages...
  \fancyfoot{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % ...and of the lines
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

Thanks to [a response here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=12891&start=20)